# webapi 5.2.3 Multiple controller types were found that match the URL - Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I've hit an issue with webapi attribute routing.  I am calling the following route: `assessment/assessments/assessmenttypes` as an `HttpPost`.  I'm getting the error that multiple controller types match the url.  The problem is that they definitely don't match.  Initially when I first got this issue I was using different route prefixes, however I read that webapi can ignore route prefixes, so I changed all the routes to make them unique, so the only `HttpPost`s which are in the "matching controllers" are defined as follows:

`[Route("assessments"), HttpPost]
 public async Task<System.Int32> PostCreate([FromBody]Assessment assessment)`

and

`[Route("assessments/assessmenttypes"), HttpPost]
 public async Task<System.Int32> PostCreate([FromBody]AssessmentType assessmentType)`

Both controllers have the same RoutePrefix of: `[RoutePrefix("assessment")]`

Can anyone help please, this is very frustrating.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to understand first at all is how routing works, that's the key to solve your problem. I can update my answer later if you give me more information (at this moment it looks like you didn't post all the required information)

As you know, routing is the process of matching **requests to routes**.
The handler that does the magic is the **HttpRoutingDispatcher** with some help of extra libraries, but basically the dispatcher resolves the request. The final goal of processing the route is to identify two elements:

- Route
- Values

You have two different ways of resolving routes, convention-based (templates) or by attributes. It's a good idea to be consistent to avoid confusions specially when the application grows.
The routing has two different parts, fixed segments (they must match exactly) and variables (denoted as you know by {})

The request verbs are matched in two different ways, with the attribute 
**[HttpGet] [HttpPost] [HttpPut]**
Or confusingly in my opinion using the first part of the method, if you have 3 different methods not marked with attributes the WebApi assumes the first letters try to indicate the verb:

- GetList  --> HttpGet of List
- GetDetail --> HttpGet of Detail
- PostDetail --> HttpPost of Detail

From the official documentation if you try the following template:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```

And you make a request from Ajax like the following:

```
$.ajax("/api/today/dayofweek", {
```

The following controller will fail (nearly always)

public class TodayController : ApiController {

```
[HttpGet]
public string DayOfWeek() {
   return DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");
}

[HttpGet]
public int DayNumber() {
   return DateTime.Now.Day;
}
```

Because it's nearly impossible to establish which one is the correct one (a human being can of course, but unfortunately machines need more programming to work with fuzzy logic) :)

The problem in your case it's not both start with the same fixed route, the problem is that it's not possible to identify whether you're saying the second part belongs to a variable or it's a fixed part (it's ambiguous)
Giving you an example; how could we establish the meaning of this?

- /segmenta/segmentb
- /segmenta/segmentb/segmentc (is segment c a fixed route or a parameter?)

From an architectural point of view the reality is (based on Api design) that I don't think /assestmenttypes is a subordinated resource of /assestments. If you want to design a RESTful ROA Api assestmenttypes are correctly indicated as a resource if the type depends on the assestment (as a child, not as an attribute).
I would suggest you to review your paths too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I'm not using route templates, only attribute routing, so I've not set a default route of `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"`.  There are no parameters in either of the URL's, it's a pretty bog standard use of webapi.  As you can see by the routes, they are not the same, this is why I'm struggling with this, as I have other routes working just fine.

Comment: Even when you're not using routing I think the main issue is the routes overlap anyways. When you declare attributes they're added to the routing collection and both are pretty similar so the routing system has a conflict establishing the correct one.

Comment: So what you're saying is that webapi only looks at the first part of a URL, and doesn't evaluate the full path?  So for instance an HttpGet at the address:  `users/books` and one for `users/groups` would evaluate to the same and would cause a conflict?

Comment: No, the webapi has some issues evaluating paths that are a subset of the other one. For example, ,users/books and users/books/new. I'm trying to think on a route that could work for you.

Comment: Hi Maximiliano, I've merged multiple controllers into less which stops the issue.  I think it's bad that webapi doesn't evaluate the full path, it seems strange, and feels like a bug tbh.  Thanks for your help I'll mark this as answered.  I would rather not have merged several logically separated controllers, but I haven't time to spend it on banging my head against the wall with this one :-)

Comment: Look, I set your methods in one of my projects and it works perfectly. So I think you have another kind of conflict, like some other routing being added to the routing collection. Or might be the WebApi version or something like that. I repeat, I set your methods, post to both routes and it works smooth.